# How to prove a limit is irrational

Tags: limits

There is a sequence $x_n$ such that $x_n^2 - 7 \le \frac 1{16}  (x_{n-1}^2-7)^2$

How does this show the limit of $x_n$ is irrational?

(Also, $2\le x_n \le  \frac 72$ and each $x_n$ is rational)

Thank you!

Comment: @Bernard As written (I did not remove anything significant with my edit), the limit might as well be $2$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Oooh! yes. I read too fast.